# Access parent environment or sibling in Lua

Tags: lua, parent, environment

I have several simultaneously running Lua scripts, and I occasionally want to read a value from a different script running under the same parent. Each separate script has its own environment, and I have no control over the parent and how it executes my code, but all the code is executed by the same parent. I'm wanting to be able to do something like:

```
parent.sibling.func()
```

Unfortunately, I can't find anything about how to get my logical parent or a sibling from within my code in any of the lua docs. I can only see from a stack trace that the children appear to be running under the same parent.

I should note that this is a moderately secure sandbox environment, and debug has been removed from the environment.

Comment: How are you running the scripts simultaneously? Coroutines? Some kind of threading library?

Comment: @luther - Not entirely certain how the parent handles that. I put the scripts in through an editor, parent executes them. I would have to decompile everything to see how it's working under the hood, which would break the EULA.

Comment: Lua is under a libre license. If you're using additional software that has a restrictive EULA, please specify that in the question.

Comment: What does "parent" mean in your question?  Is it a "host application"?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - from the best I can tell, the parent is another Lua script. I'm guessing it's running my scripts via something like a ```pcall(load(<myScript>))``` inside a coroutine, and setting up an environment for my code, but I can't be exactly certain.

Comment: @luther - Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to disclose the environment that is executing the Lua at this time. I've added that I'm working in a secure sandbox environment, which is about as much as I can say about the environment specifically.